# R ggplot custom spaces between ticks when using scale_x_date

Tags: r

The data I am collecting is at irregular date intervals. I am using scale_x_date to specify which dates to display in the x-axis of the plot. However, because of the irregularity of the dates, the spaces between the ticks on the axis aren't even (i.e. there is a big gap between the 2020 and 2021 data points). Is there a way to build on the scale_x_date code so that the spaces between the dates are even?

```
scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date(c("[2020-010-01", "2020-11-27", "2021-07-15][1]")))
```

Comment: One option would be to convert the dates to a factor and use a discrete scale. Then each date will be evenly spaced from its neighbors regardless of the time difference.

Comment: I've seen this suggested elsewhere, but at the expense of chronological order. Can I maintain the date order if I convert it to a factor?

Comment: Sure. `dates <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2021-04-15")); dates2 <- forcats::fct_reorder(format(dates, "%b %d, '%y"), dates)` is an example where the dates have a custom format but are ordered chronologically and will display that way in ggplot2.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are in YMD format, they **will** be numbered in chronological (=alphabetical in YMD format) order:

```
df = data.frame(
  Date = c("2020-10-01", "2021-07-15", "2020-11-27"),
  Value = 11:13
)
df = df[order(df$Date),]
labels = unique(df$Date)
ggplot(df, aes(as.numeric(factor(Date)), Value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:length(labels), labels=labels, name="")
```